# How to send index from a table as a parameter in struts using hyperlink

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, indexing, struts

I am creating a table displaying following values,

```
<tr>                               
  <th scope="col"><bean:message key="label.booking.history.received" /></th>
  <th scope="col"><bean:message key="label.booking.history.dealt" /></th>
  <th scope="col"><bean:message key="label.booking.history.customer" /></th>
  <th scope="col"><bean:message key="label.booking.history.report" /></th>                              
</tr>
<logic:iterate id="itemDetails" indexId="index" name="bookingHistorySearchForm" property="results.currentPage" >
  <tr class="even">                                 
    <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="recived"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="dealt"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="customer"/></td>
    <td><bean:write name="itemDetails" property="downloadLink"/></td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```

Now, I want to show 4th column as a hyperlink and it will call an action and send row number as a parameter.

I tried using

```
<td>
  <html:link  action="/pages/bookings/details/bookingHistoryDownload" paramId="index" property="<%=selectImgButton%>" >
    <bean:message key="link.booking.viewHistory"/>
  </html:link>
</td>
```

but it is not sending the value of index.

Answer (score 0):

In the hyperlink you should define two attributes one is `paramId` that will contain a name of the parameter and `paramName` which will hold the value. So, to send an index as a parameter you don't need a `property` attribute.

```
<html:link action="/pages/bookings/details/bookingHistoryDownload" paramId="index" paramName="${index}">
  <bean:message key="link.booking.viewHistory"/>
</html:link>
```